# Get app's app store ID or bundle identifier from executable file name

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

I get running processes name/pIDs on my device by following 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312613/can-we-retrieve-the-applications-currently-running-in-iphone-and-ipad) 
link and get the name of the executable binary file from this
 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160013/programmatically-get-the-directory-path-of-other-application-from-process-pid-on) . I need to associate this binary filename or the process name with the app store id or bundle identifier of the name so that i can get the app's info from the app store. Any suggestions on how to do this? I know this can be done easily on a jail broken device, but i want to submit my app to app store so any legal way to do this?